# How to track a page view using google app engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, analytics, app-engine-ndb

I have a web app which lets users submit a blog post. I would like to track the page views of every blog post page. So when some visits:

```
/post/123
```

A user's visitor should see the number of people who have visited this page.

One seemingly unscalable solution I thought of is to add a page_views property to the Blog kind:

```
class Blog(ndb.Model):
    title = ndb.StringProperty()
    page_views = ndb.IntegerProperty()
```

Then, whenever the page is visited, just do `blog.page_views` plus 1. Then `blog.put()`. However, this attempt would mean that we would be writing too frequently to the db.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Because of consistency issues in ndb, writing to a counter in the datastore may be wildly inaccurate, especially if your app gets a lot of traffic.  One of your instances might read a current count of 1234 `page_views`, then try to write 1235 to the datastore.  But, in the meantime, may other visitors may have come, and they will all see the same `page_views` value.  Plus, because of consistency, the read you obtained may be a minute stale.  So, your 1235 may actually be 1278, or even larger.

To avoid so many writes, consider making your counter in memcache, then increase the count there.  Memcache persists across instances, and values change almost instantaneously.  Then, periodically dump the Memcache count to the datastore, incrementing there, and delete it.

Example, any time a visitor views a post, increment the memcache count, and set a deferred task for 5 minutes later to persist the count to the datastore.  That way, you collect 5 minutes worth of views into one write op.

Memcache is prone to failure, so your counts will never be 100% accurate.  But, dumping every 5 minutes or so reduces the error.

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to have a very accurate page view count yes, you'd have to persist it in the datastore and you'd have to address the risk of exceeding the max entity group writing rate of ~1/sec. The typical approach in this case is [Sharding counters](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/sharding_counters?csw=1).

However if you're OK with potentially missing a few views now and then (which IMHO could be perfectly acceptable) you could use a different strategy, using memcache where you'd store a counter and a timestamp, which you can tune to be much more relaxed in terms of datastore operations. On every page view you'd invoke a transactional function (to prevent corrupting the datastore counter value) which would:

- increment the memcache counter value (or set it to 1 if missing or invalid)
- check the memcache timestamp value and, if valid and "recent enough" (tunable) it'd just return, otherwise continue
- update the memcache timestamp with the current time (to prevent, together with the next step, a race condition with the same function invoked for another concurrent request)
- add the memcache counter value to the datastore counter value and save the datastore counter; if this transaction fails it means some other concurrent request is doing it already, nothing to do (the function would end at this point)
- reset the memcache counter to zero
- optional, not needed if you don't expect long enough inactivity periods during which you risk losing a significant amount of views accumulated in the memory counter which can dissapear at any time - enqueue a delayed task (or a deferred one, if you prefer to use the deferred library) which would also invoke this same transactional function, except in that run:

  - it won't increment the memcache counter value
  - it won't enqueue another delayed task

I'd pick the task delay value equal with the "recent enough" one.

By tuning the "recent enough" value you control how often you update the datastore counter value.

When you want to display the number of views you'd just read the datastore value and the memcache value (in this order, to prevent a possible race condition in which you'd count the memcache counter value twice) and add them to obtain the visits count.